# "The South" by Jorge Luis Borges: book/movie differences?

Tags: short-stories, spanish-language, jorge-luis-borges, adaptation-comparison

What are some of the differences and similarities between the book "The South" and the movie? The book is about Juan Dahlmann with his accident. I know that the cat is in different places, that the accidents are different, and there is a fight in the movie. But does anyone know any other differences?